# How to know if the web application is running on desktop or mobile without using viewport size or user agent?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, progressive-web-apps

I am building a pwa and basically what I need to do is save a value in the local storage only if the web app is opened on a mobile device and prevent that value from being saved when using chrome dev tools to simulate the size of a mobile in the desktop version.

I've searched but the two solutions i've found where using media queries or user agent. With media queries the value is saved just by resizing the viewport so is not a solution and with user agent the value is saved when toggleing device toolbar in the browser inspector so it is not a solution either.

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: `when toggleing device toolbar in the browser inspector` well thats totally expected so i dont see your problem here, what else did you try?

Comment: you could also check for touchscreen

Comment: I've used a function that returns true or false if the user agent variable contains a mobile device name or not. The problem is that if im using the web app in desktop and i toggle the device toolbar, to see the mobile version, the function returns true as if it were on a mobile, and that sholud not happen.

Comment: @johnSmith That is a good idea, thank you very much! I'll try.